# Is it Possible to connect SAP Server and JAVA without JCO?

Tags: java, jco

Is there any way to **connect SAP Server through JAVA without using JCO**? 
If any suggestions, thanx in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at SAP Web Application Server [Web
   Services Documentation](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/9b/dad1ae3908ee44a5caf57e10918be9/content.htm). You can use the SOAP Runtime to expose and consume both ABAP and Java Web Services.

Comment: Thanx for your response. I need to connect a SAP Server with Java in my desktop application (Swing Project) not in Web Application.
I don't want to place ".DLL" files in the installation directory of all my systems in which I am going to use this application.Is there anyway for connecting JAVA to the SAP Server without using JCo & .DLL files? Any suggestions appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You can expose your ABAP Web services in the server and consume then in a standalone (Desktop) Java Applicaion with, for example, a [JAX-WS Client](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html#bnayx) generated by [wsimport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html). No DLLs required.